# Storing user submitted forms

Tags: database, users, forms, user-meta

I was wondering what's the best way to create a form which can only be seen by registered users. The main idea I'd like to achieve here is for users to log in and gain access to a page where there's an application form which can be submitted multiple times. Each form will be stored on the database and associated with the user. It'll also have the option to attach files to the system.

In the WP dashboard, the administrator can browse all the users in the system and see all the applications they have submitted. Would it be best to create a custom tab in the dashboard and display each user?

Would the form data be classified as meta data for each user? I'm a little confused in terms of how to develop this, any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will require to custom develop some part of it but most of it can be done with [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) plugin.

You can create forms with upload fields very easily in **Contact Form 7**. And you can make it visible for loggenin users only like this.

```
<?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="91" title="Form"]');
    }
?>
```

Although Contact Form 7 doesn’t save the submitted messages by default, but Contact Form 7 developer also created another plugin [Flamingo](http://wordpress.org/plugins/flamingo/) to save entries in database. Admin can see those entries in admin panel.

Comment: I was definitely looking at contact form 7 - I'm trying to find the easiest way to get a working solution out the door - the form doesn't have to be dynamic, is there a way to update contact form 7 so that an update to the plugin won't overwrite my code?

Comment: No, you don't need to change source code of Contact Form 7 plugin, so you will be able to update plugins without worrying. All you need to do is create a form in Contact Form 7 from WordPress admin panel. Then it will supply a shortcode for that form to display on website. Then you can use use above code (posted by me) and change it with your form shortcode and paste it in your theme files (where you want to use) to display form to logged in users only.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on how much work you're wanting to put in. Gravity Forms plugin will do most of what you want (with some customization), or you could write something completely from scratch: maybe something like registering an "application" CPT that has all info as meta data, and you can sort/filter by user. I don't think adding all applications to user meta makes sense (potential to be a massive array), but it should certainly work.

Comment: Gravity Forms is paid plugin and I think you hsould not suggest it unless there are no free solution available.

Comment: @Roberthue in my experience, free form plugins are unreliable, and I will always recommend the plugin I've had the best experience with first.

Comment: Don't know about what type of plugins you use but I have had best experience with only free plugins. And if you limit yourself to popular plugins in directory, then you will never regret your decision.